# MS Access Select Top 2 most recent dates relative to ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with a large list of IDs for people

And for each ID there are many dates

example

```
ID
1 21/09/2016
1 24/09/2016 
3 09/01/2017
3 04/01/2016
3 31/12/2016
13 1/10/2016
13 1/11/2016
4 12/12/2016
```

I am needing to write a Microsoft Access Query that returns a table which select the TOP 2 most recent dates for each id. So for ID 3 (in table above) it would return 09/01/2017 and 04/01/2017 as these are the two most recent dates for that id.

Any idea?

Comment: Sorry the table came out funny and messy. It's a two column table. First column ID and second column DATE

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  Have you tried something?

Comment: Hi, no this is a work problem - I've tried a few things but they aren't working so I won't even include the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select A.ID, A.Date 
from  (
        Select Id, Date , 
        Rank() OVER (Partition by Id order by Date Desc) as daterank 
        from tablename
      ) A
Where A.daterank < 3
```

Comment: Thank you for that - I'm getting a syntax error though on the partition line, I believe it's because I'm using Microsoft access and it doesn't like it? Is that for SQL but not MS Access?